# Navier-Stokes Millennium problem for four and above four dimensions

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Is the analog of Navier-Stokes Millennium problem for four and above four dimensions already solved?

Comment: It might make sense to be slightly more specific what you want to ask about. That is formulate a specific mathematical question.